# Avoid percent-encoding href attributes when using PHP's DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, xslt, domdocument, percent-encoding

The best answers I was able to find for this issue are using XSLT, but I'm just not sure how to apply those answers to my problem.

Basically, DOMDocument is doing a fine job of escaping URLs (in `href` attributes) that are passed in, but I'm actually using it to build a Twig/Django style template, and I'd rather it leave them alone. Here's a specific example, illustrating the "problem":

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<html><body>Test<br><a href="{{variable}}"></a></body></html>');
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Which outputs the following:

```
<html><body>Test<br><a href="%7B%7Bvariable%7D%7D"></a></body></html>
```

**Is it possible to NOT percent-encode the `href` attribute?**

If it's not possible *directly*, can you suggest a concise and reliable workaround? I'm doing other processing, and the DOMDocument usage will have to stay. So perhaps a pre/post processing trick?

Comment: DOM is great for manipulating an existing document, but for building a new doc from the ground up, it's better to just use string operations, especially when you're building a "template that looks like html".

Comment: I am actually manipulating an existing document. This is the shortest possible sample code that clearly illustrated the problem.

Comment: Essentially the string used in this example would have been loaded via `file_get_contents()`, *for example*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not happy with the 'hack'/duct-tape solution, but this is how I'm currently solving the problem:

```
function fix_template_variable_tokens($template_string)
{
    $pattern = "/%7B%7B(\w+)%7D%7D/";
    $replacement = '{{$1}}';
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $template_string);
}

$html = $doc->saveHTML();
$html = fix_template_variable_tokens($html);
```

Comment: Yeah but this is better than the `urldecode` solution :D